# Append to array for each item of a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops

With the following code:

```
class Calendar_Data(Resource):
  def get(self):
    result = []
    details_array = []
    # Times are converted to seconds
    for day in life.days:
      for span in day.spans:
        if type(span.place) is str:
          details = {
            'name': span.place,
            'date': 0,
            'value': (span.length() * 60),
          }
          details_array.append(details)
      data = {
        'date': datetime.datetime.strptime(day.date, '%Y_%m_%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        'total': (day.somewhere() * 60),
        'details': details_array
      }
      result.append(data)
    return result
```

What I'm trying to do is for each day that is present in a list of days, get the corresponding spans for that day, and fill the array with the `details`. Then pass that `details` to the `data` array in order to have it for each day of that list of days.

The problem here is when I use these nested loops above, it fills me the `details` with the all the spans from all days, instead of each single day.

I don't thin using a `zip` in this case would work. Maybe some list comprehension but I still did not understand that fully.

Example input:

```
--2016_01_15
@UTC
0000-0915: home
0924-0930: seixalinho station
1000-1008: cais do sodre station
1009-1024: cais do sodre station->saldanha station
1025-1027: saldanha station
1030-1743: INESC
1746-1750: saldanha station
1751-1815: saldanha station->cais do sodre station
1815-1834: cais do sodre station {Waiting for the boat trip back. The boat was late}
1920-2359: home [dinner]

--2016_01_16
0000-2136: home
2147-2200: fabio's house
2237-2258: bar [drinks]
```

For the sixteenth of january the details array is supposed to have 3 items, but each day constantly shows all of the items of all days.

Comment: Can you please add an example of your input, your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: @IanAuld I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't redeclaring your list (Python has lists not arrays) in between each loop. You need to move the creation of your `details_array` inside one of the loops so it is recreated as empty. You'll likely wnt it to look like this:

```
for day in life.days:
    details_array = []
    for span in day.spans:
```

This way for each new iteration of a `day` you'll have a new empty list.